# How to merge multiple JSON objects to one single json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

My requirement is to get the json objects from different sources and merge them into one single json object using javascript

example:
Below there are 2 json objects with different values and I want to make it as one final Json object and append new value to the final result

json1= {
"b":"test1",
"a":"test3",
"type":"sample1"
}

json2=  {
"endDate":"ddd1",
"startDate":"dd01"
}

Expected results should be like below

result = {
"b":"test1",
"a":"test3",
"type":"sample1",
"endDate":"ddd1",
"startDate":"dd01"
}

Can anyone suggest me the best way to achieve this in javascript please ?

Comment: What about `type` property?

Comment: What is `XYZ` property?

Comment: please make your question bit more clear.

Comment: I am not expecting type property in resulted object.

Comment: “XYZ” new property Key and the corresponding Value is in object1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the rest operator to remove type property and then assign values from 1st object to new property of the merged object

```
let mergeObjects = (a, b) => {

    let {type, ...rest} = b; //remove type property
    for(let prop in rest){
        if(a[prop]){
            rest[prop].xyz = a[prop]; 
        }
    }
    return rest;
}

let Object3= mergeObjects(Object1, Object2);
console.log(Object3);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response

Answer (score 0):

---

---

Can be as simple as this:

```js
let Object1 ={"b":"test1","a":"test3","type":"sample1"};let Object2 ={"b":{"endDate":"ddd1","startDate":"dd01"},"a":{"endDate":"31","startDate":"01"},"type":"sample2"}

let Object3 = Object2;
for (let i in Object3){
  Object3[i]["XYZ"] = Object1[i]
}
Object3["type"] = "12345"
console.log(Object3)
```

Comment: No problem @VijayKesanupalli, remember to upvote my answer and choose it if you think it solves your issue.

Comment: If I want to modify type property value with some different value (ex: type:12345)in the resulted object please advise

Comment: Can you elaborate? Not sure what you are asking

Comment: Your results are like below { "b": { "endDate": "ddd1", "startDate": "dd01", "XYZ": "test1" }, "a": { "endDate": "31", "startDate": "01", "XYZ": "test3" }, "type": "sample2" }

Comment: But I am expecting [ "b": { "endDate": "ddd1", "startDate": "dd01", "XYZ": "test1" }, "a": { "endDate": "31", "startDate": "01", "XYZ": "test3" }, "type": "12345" ]

Comment: Can you please advise

Comment: Edited the code. You can run it and see. @VijayKesanupalli

Comment: Thanks, Here is the results { "b": { "endDate": "ddd1", "startDate": "dd01", "XYZ": "test1" }, "a": { "endDate": "31", "startDate": "01", "XYZ": "test3" }, "type": "12345" } Results are accurate but I am expecting in an array like ["b": { "endDate": "ddd1", "startDate": "dd01", "XYZ": "test1" }, "a": { "endDate": "31", "startDate": "01", "XYZ": "test3" }, "type": "12345" ]